# Send Ajax Array to Controller

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

[image]

[image]

Above I have showed the my dynamic UI and the way I set the ids dynamically for the relevant fields according to the date.

So I need to send theses data into MVC controller as a array ajax post and then pick those things inside the controller.This should be happened when I click **Save** button

My post method is as below (without above array details):

```
 $("#clocked-details").find("#btnSave").die('click').live('click', function () {

       var yearValue = $("#year").val();
       var monthValue = $("#month").val();

       $.ajax({
          url: "/Employees/UpdateEmployeeClockedHoursByProvider",
          type: 'POST',
          cache: false,
          data: { employeeId: employeeId, year: yearValue, month: monthValue },
          success: function (result) {

          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 alert(xhr.status);
                 alert(thrownError);
               }
           });
          return false;
       });
```

My controller is as below (without jquery array maupulation) :

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateEmployeeClockedHoursByProvider(Guid employeeId, int year, int month)
        {

        }
```

**Update**

UI has been generated by using below mentioned code :

```
<% foreach (var ec in Model)
       {%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="<%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>-hours" name="<%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>-hours"
                class="total-hours" placeholder="Hours" value="<%: ec.TotalHours %>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="<%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>-minutes" name="<%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>-minutes"
                class="total-minutes" placeholder="Minutes" value="<%: ec.TotalMinutes %>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% }%>
```

**My Questions :**

1. How to send above dynamic 2 fields per row data by using ajax ?
2. How to manipulate that array inside the controller ?

Comment: Dynamic 2 Fields in the sense ?
The textboxes generated by MVC Helper dynamically ?

Comment: @Vitthal plz check my "Update" section.

Comment: @Vitthal Then how can I get each and every rows value from server side ?

Comment: You want to send the dates in attribute `id` which is say `2013-03-08` ?

Comment: `data: $('tr').serialize()` gets all the input values under every row into ur Ajax `data` variable

Comment: @Vitthal Nope I need to send totalhours and totlminutes which are input by users for the text boxes which are generating dynamically against the date.As I showed on my UI.

Comment: `data: $('tr').serialize()` gets all values of your input box for example--- 

<br>

`<input type="number" id="<%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>-minutes" name="<%: ec.ClockedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>-minutes"
                class="total-minutes" placeholder="Minutes" value="<%: ec.TotalMinutes %>" />`
<br>
It takes `<%: ec.TotalMinutes %>` and sends with Id of Date which is 2013-03-08

Comment: @Vitthal Actually I would like to send only the data required for the processing inside server side rather than every thing by using jqury array Technic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26282/discussion-between-vitthal-and-sampath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by defining a view model on the server that will represent the data you would like to retrieve:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }

    public ItemViewModel[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int TotalHours { get; set; }
    public int TotalMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateEmployeeClockedHoursByProvider(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

The next step is to fix your view a little bit because right now you seem to be hardcoding input fields instead of using html helpers and defining wrong ids and names for your input fields (in HTML the `id` and `name` attribute cannot start with a number).

So here's how you could generate the table:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEmployeeClockedHoursByProvider", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })) { %>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Clocked Date</th>
                <th>Total Hours</th>
                <th>Total Minutes</th>
            <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ClockedDate) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(
                        x => x[i].TotalHours, 
                        new { 
                            type = "number", 
                            placeholder = "Hours", 
                            @class = "total-hours" 
                        }
                    ) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(
                        x => x[i].TotalMinutes, 
                        new { 
                            type = "number", 
                            placeholder = "Minutes", 
                            @class = "total-minutes" 
                        }
                    ) %>
                </td>                    
            </tr>
        <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
<% } %>
```

and finally you could have some javascript file that will subscribe to the `.submit` handler of the form and send the values to the server:

```
$(document).on('#myForm', 'submit', function () {
    var items = [];
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        items.push({
            totalHours: $(this).find('td input.total-hours').val(),
            totalMinutes: $(this).find('td input.total-minutes').val()
        });
    });

    var data = {
        employeeId: employeeId, // <!-- It's not very clear from your code where is this supposed to come from
        year: $('#year').val(),
        month: $('#month').val(),
        items: items
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            // TODO: here you could handle the response from the server
            alert('Your request has been successfully processed.');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

In this example notice how I used the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of `.live()` which is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Unbelievable.This is the answer which was on my head.But b'cos of lack of jquery json handling knowledge I couldn't convert it in to your kind of solution.So I don't know how could I thanks for you.Great Answer. Awesome.Keep it up your good work for SO.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is for your no.1 querstions.

you can send all form data using `form.serialize()`. eg

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $('#yourformId').serialize(),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Do you know any method to send the required data only without sending every form contents ?